# Do the windmills $K_5^{(3)}$ and $K_5^{(4)}$ admit graceful labellings?

Tags: graph-theory

Here $K_n^{(k)}$ is the windmill formed by taking $k$ copies of $K_n$ and gluing them at a vertex.  A [*graceful labelling*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GracefulLabeling.html) of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a vertex labelling $f:V \rightarrow \{0,\ldots,|E|\}$ such that different vertices get different labels and $|f(i)-f(j)|$ is distinct for distinct edges $\{i,j\}$.  For example this is a graceful labelling of $K_3^{(4)}$ I drew by hand:

> [[image: A graceful labelling of <span class=]$K_3^{(4)}$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN2vd.png)

Most of the time, windmills cannot be gracefully labelled:

> A necessary condition for $K_n^{(k)}$ to be graceful is that $n \leq 5$.
> <sub>Gallian, [*A Dynamic Survey of Graph Labeling*](https://doi.org/10.37236/27), Electron. J. Combin., 2017+.</sub>

I searched the literature and found a gajillion papers on the topic, within which I found:

|  | k=1 | k=2 | k=3 | k=4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n=2 | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| n=3 | ✓ | ✗ (Graham, Sloane, [pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/80_07_harmonious.pdf)) | ✗ (Bermond, Kotzig, Turgeon, [pdf](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02322841/document)) | ✓ (see above) |
| n=4 | ✓ | ✗ (Graham, Sloane, [pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/80_07_harmonious.pdf)) | ✗ (Bermond, Kotzig, Turgeon, [pdf](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02322841/document)) | ✓ (Bermond, [pdf](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02340680/document); [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc9K2.png)) |
| n=5 | ✗ | ✗ (Graham, Sloane, [pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/80_07_harmonious.pdf)) | ? | ? |

When $n=2$, we have a star, and that's easy (put a zero in the middle).  When $k=1$, we have a complete graph, and there's a bunch of references in the Gallian survey.

I didn't find answers for $K_5^{(3)}$ and $K_5^{(4)}$.  I'm expecting this to be in the literature (or maybe on someone's computer).

**Question**: Do the windmills $K_5^{(3)}$ and $K_5^{(4)}$ admit graceful labellings?

I whipped up [some GAP code](https://pastebin.com/XX1xmpRR) (and [an improved version](https://pastebin.com/mLe9ESEc)); it was able to confirm the known results, but it's too slow for $K_5^{(3)}$ and $K_5^{(4)}$.  It found graceful labellings of $K_3^{(5)}$ and $K_4^{(5)}$ though:

> [[image: A graceful labelling of <span class=]$K_3^{(5)}$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5yjq.png)

> [[image: A graceful labelling of <span class=]$K_4^{(5)}$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZGbf.png)

Comment: My brute-force wasn't able to find a labelling for any of the two.

Comment: I'd expect that a SAT solver should be able to confirm the nonexistence of a graceful labeling in these two cases. Introduce Boolean variables $x_{ij}$ to indicate that vertex $i$ gets label $j$ and Boolean variables $y_{ij}$ to indicate that edge $i$ gets label $j$. It is not hard to write down all the necessary constraints as SAT clauses. I'd also recommend adding a few symmetry-breaking constraints to speed up the computation.

Comment: My little C program says that neither $K_5^{(3)}$ nor $K_5^{(4)}$ have graceful labellings. It took 3 seconds and 4 minutes, respectively. This confirms Mikhail's result so I think this is sufficient verification.

Comment: Actually, 2 seconds and 2 minutes once I realized that the reverse of a labelling is also a labelling.  Now I wonder about $K_5^{(5)}$ — is anything known.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay By Bosák's result in my answer, $K_5^{(2j+1)}$ for $j\ge0$ is ungraceful.

Comment: @hoboonsuan Thanks, that saves me some computing time.  I have $K_5^{(4)}$ down to 20 seconds and wonder if $K_5^{(6)}$ is plausible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partial answer: a result of Juraj Bosák says that if all vertices of a graceful graph have even degree, then the graph has $4k$ or $4k+3$ edges for some integer $k$ (proof given below).

Since $K_5^{(3)}$ has $30$ edges, it is ungraceful.

Gallian's survey attributes this result to [Rosa 1967].
See also Don Knuth's work-in-progress section 7.2.2.3 of *The Art of Computer Programming* ([https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc7a.ps.gz](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fasc7a.ps.gz)) for a computational discussion graceful labelings as constraint satisfaction problems.

**Lemma 7.2.2.3O from *The Art of Computer Programming*.** *In any graceful labeling of a graph with $4k+1$ or $4k+2$ edges, the number of vertices with an odd degree and an odd label is always odd.*

**Proof.** We have $\sum_{uv\in E(G)}|l(u)-l(v)|=1+2+\dots+m=\binom{m+1}{2}$ when there are $m$ edges; and a given vertex $v$ appears exactly $\deg(v)$ times in this sum. Working modulo $2$, we also have $|l(u)-l(v)|\equiv l(u)+l(v)$. Therefore $\sum_v\deg(v)l(v)\equiv\binom{m+1}{2}$. But $\binom{m+1}{2}\equiv1$ when $m=4k+1$ or $m=4k+2$. $\square$

---

#### Overview: gracefulness of windmill graphs $K_n^{(j)}$

| $n$ $\backslash$ $j$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ | $7$ | $j\ge8$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $2$ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| $3$ | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ | ✓ | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ | ✓ if and only if $j\equiv0\hbox{ or }1\pmod4$ |
| $4$ | ✓ | ✗ | ✗ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ if $j\le1000$; ? otherwise |
| $5$ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ? | ✗ | ✗ if $j$ is odd; ? if $j$ is even |
| $n\ge6$ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ |

When $n=2$, $K_2^{(j)}=K_{1,j}$ is a [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) and can always be gracefully labeled by placing $0$ in the internal vertex.

When $n=3$, $K_3^{(j)}$ is a [friendship graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph) and is graceful if and only if $j\equiv0\hbox{ or }1\pmod4$.
The forward implication follows from J. Bosák's result in [Rosa 1965], and the reverse implication follows from a construction of [Skolem 1957].

When $n=4$ and $4\le j\le1000$, $K_n^{(j)}$ is graceful due to a construction of [Ge et al. 2010] (they construct $(12j+1,4,1)$-perfect distance families for $4\le j\le1000$, which are equivalent to graceful labelings of $K_4^{(j)}$).
When $j>1000$, nothing is known, though [Bermond 1979] conjectures that $K_4^{(j)}$ is graceful for $j\ge4$.

When $n=5$, if $j$ is odd, Bosák's result implies that $K_5^{(j)}$ is ungraceful. For even $j\ge6$, nothing is known.

When $n\ge6$, a result of [Koh et al. 1980] implies that $K_n^{(j)}$ is always ungraceful.

---

#### References

[Skolem 1957]
Thoralf A. Skolem,
*On Certain Distributions of Integers In Pairs With Given Differences*.
Mathematica Scandinavica **5** (1957), 57–68.
https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10490

[Rosa 1965]
Alexander Rosa,
*O Cyklických Rozkladoch Kompletného Grafu, Kandidátska dizertačná práca*. (Bratislava: Českoslovanská akadémia vied, November 1965), ii+86 pages. (Note: Rosa attributes the result above to J. Bosák on page 17).
https://archive.org/details/o-cyklickych-rozkladoch-kompletneho-garfu

[Rosa 1967]
Alexander Rosa,
*On certain valuations of the vertices of a graph*.
Theory of Graphs (International Symposium, Rome, July 1966),
Gordon and Breach, N. Y. and Dunod Paris (1967), 349–355.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244474213_On_certain_valuations_of_the_vertices_of_a_graph

[Bermond 1979]
Jean-Claude Bermond,
*Graceful graphs, radio antennae and French windmills*.
In Graph Theory and Combinatorics (ed. R. J. Wilson),
Research Notes in Mathematics **34** (1979), 18–37.
(Proceedings of a one-day conference in combinatorics and graph theory held at the Open University, England, on 12 May 1978.)
https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02340680

[Koh et al. 1980]
Khee Meng Koh, D. G. Rogers, H. K. Teo, and K. Y. Yap,
*Graceful graphs: some further results and problems*.
Congressus Numerantium **29**:
Proceedings of the 11th Southeastern Conference on Combinatorics, Graph Theory, and Computing, Winnipeg, Manitoba (December 1980), 559–571

[Ge et al. 2010]
Gennian Ge, Ying Miao, and Xianwei Sun,
*Perfect difference families, perfect difference matrices and related combinatorial structures*.
Journal of Combinatorial Designs **18**(6) (2010), 415–449.
https://doi.org/10.1002/jcd.20259

[Knuth 2021]
Donald E. Knuth,
*The Art of Computer Programming* Volume 4 Pre-Fascicle 7A, Section 7.2.2.3: Constraint Satisfaction (2020–).
[https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc7a.ps.gz](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fasc7a.ps.gz)